# await with try/catch and nested promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

Perhaps a bit of a dumb question but should I catch the promise within the method entitled "actionTwo()" ? What is best practice?

```
async actionOne(req, res, next) {
    try {
        await this.actionTwo();
    } catch( error ) => {
       // catch the error
    }
}

async actionTwo(req, res, next) {
    return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
        // do something
        resolve()
    })
    .catch( error ) {
        // Do I need this catch statement???
        reject( error )
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer at present because `actionTwo` shouldn't be written that way in the first place. :-) Is "do something" a process that *already* results in a promise, or some other form of async thing (for instance, that has a callback)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catch the error in whatever function can *handle* the error. This may be one function, or both functions, or neither function.

In your example, if `actionTwo` needs to do something whenever it encounters an error (for example, log that `actionTwo` failed), then you should indeed `catch` inside of it. But if `actionTwo` itself *doesn't* need to do anything particular when it encounters an error, don't `.catch` inside it, and instead just return the rejected Promise so that its consumer (here, `actionOne`) can handle the error.

If `actionOne` can see the error and do something useful as a result (eg, log that `actionOne` failed, or render an error page, or something like that), then `actionOne` should catch the error. Otherwise, there's not much use to catching the error, and you should just return the `actionOne` Promise (automatically created by the `async` function) for the consumer of `asyncOne` to handle.

Ultimately, all errors should be caught *somewhere*, else you'll get unhandled rejections.

Keep in mind that if a called function needs to handle an error, *and* its consumer needs to see and handle the error too, the called function will have to re-throw the error in its `catch`, eg:

```
async actionOne(req, res, next) {
    try {
        await this.actionTwo();
    } catch( error ) => {
       // catch the error
    }
}

async actionTwo(req, res, next) {
    return new Promise( function( resolve, reject ) {
        // do something
        resolve()
    })
    .catch( error ) {
        // handle error
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice answer

Answer (score 1):

Usually no, `actionTwo` wouldn't catch rejections, it would pass them on to its caller (which in turn might pass them to *its* caller, etc.).

At the top level, where you no longer have an `async` function, you usually catch errors and report them in some appropriate way.

Obviously, there are exceptions to this rule (no pun intended). If `actionTwo` can meaningfully convert a rejection into a fulfillment, then yes it would make sense for it to do so.

---

Note that the `actionTwo` in the question either shouldn't be `async`, or shouldn't use `new Promise`, depending on what "do something" is.

In the following:

- I'll call "do something" `doSomething();`
- Based on the question, `actionOne` and `actionTwo` are methods in an object literal or class definition, so I'll use that form below

If `doSomething()` returns a promise, then `actionTwo` would look like this in the normal case:

```
actionTwo() { // No `async`
    return doSomething();
}
```

or

```
async actionTwo() {
    const x = await doSomething();
    // ...do something with `x`...
    return x;
}
```

This form is also fine:

```
async actionTwo() { // With `async`
    return doSomething();
}
```

...though unnecessary. It used to introduce one extra async "tick" (which was usually harmless), but that was recently improved in the spec and we can expect JavaScript engines to adopt the change soon.

If `doSomething` is an old-fashioned callback-style asynchronous function, then `actionTwo` would typically look like this:

```
actionTwo() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) {
        doSomething(function() {
            if (/*...the action failed...*/) {
                reject(new Error(/*...with failure information...*/));
            } else {
                resolve(/*...with the result...*/);
            }
        });
    });
}
```